# eCryptFS Initialization Issues

Tags: linux, security, encryption, arch-linux

I'm having issues with the first mount of eCryptFS. Currently when I attempt to mount it

`mount -t ecryptfs ~/.Private ~/Private`

However it's erroring. The error in `dmesg` is the following:

`Error parsing options; rc = [-22]`

This is a fresh installation of Arch and I've yet to have this issue with other distributions. I'm not quite sure what the issue is however.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears eCryptFS is now in the kernel however the extra end user utilities aren't pre-bundled with Arch (duh). The issue is they're not in the normal repository however there appears to be an AUR package that is kept up-to-date.

Long story short: install the ecryptfs-utils package